# Can you illustrate the text about angles?

Tags: triangles, angle

I want to know what does the illustration from the text below looks like:

"Prop. 9. If two triangles have an angle of the one equal to an angle of the other, and the sides about another pair of angles equal, each to each, then the third angles are either equal or supplementary."

I just took it from a scanned book named "Elementary trigonometry" from the Internet Archives website, here's the link for the book: https://archive.org/details/elementarytrigon00paterich

Thanks if the answer was illustrated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: this sounds like SSA and RHS congruence.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the image above, say you started with triangle $ABC$, you know $\angle CAB$. You also know $AC$ and $BC$. If you start from the segment $AC=A'C'$, and the angle $CAB=\angle C'A'B'$, at the distance $C'B'=CB$ there are two points (see $B$ and $D$ in the figure. Is this explanation enough?

Comment: Yep, thanks ^_^

Comment: You can also see that $CBD$ is isosceles, so you can get the supplementary angles around $D$